# Determining if a hand of cards is a flush

Tags: c++, struct, logic

I am currently working on creating a poker game and need to check if each hand of cards qualifies as a winning hand. I have an array of 52 `ACards` with the following structure:

```
struct ACard{
    int num;
    const char *pic;
};
```

and I have declared the `pic` for each card as the following:

```
const char spade[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa0";
const char club[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa3";
const char heart[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa5";
const char diamond[4] = "\xe2\x99\xa6";
```

I have created a test hand to test my logic for each of the possible winning hands.

Here is my test hand for a flush with the logic to check it as well:

```
        testHand[0] = testDeck.cards[13];
        testHand[1] = testDeck.cards[17];
        testHand[2] = testDeck.cards[19];
        testHand[3] = testDeck.cards[22];
        testHand[4] = testDeck.cards[24];

        cout << "Testing Flush" << endl;
        printHand(testHand, testDeck);

        if((testHand[0].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa0" && testHand[1].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa0" && testHand[2].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa0" && testHand[3].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa0" && testHand[4].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa0") || (testHand[0].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa5" && testHand[1].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa5" && testHand[2].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa5" && testHand[3].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa5" && testHand[4].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa5") || (testHand[0].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa3" && testHand[1].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa3" && testHand[2].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa3" && testHand[3].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa3" && testHand[4].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa3") || (testHand[0].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa6" && testHand[1].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa6" && testHand[2].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa6" && testHand[3].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa6" && testHand[4].pic == "\xe2\x99\xa6")){
            cout << "Winner Winner Chicken Dinner! Flush!" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Incorrect Logic" << endl;
        }
```

When it hits the if statement, the logic is wrong so it prints `Incorrect Logic`. I have also tried checking if each `pic` is equal to the variables `heart, diamond, club, or spade`, and just checking if each each `pic` is equal to the next cards `pic`.

I could use some help with my logic within the if statement.

Comment: You can't compare char arrays like that. You'd need to use `strcmp`, or switch to using C++ strings. Incidentally, you don't need to check if each of the cards matches the predefined suits, you can just compare each of the cards to see if they match.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but your code will be much cleaner if you use a numeric value to record the suit. `enum suit { club, diamond, heart, space };`. Now you can just compare the suit values directly, without using `strcmp`. You don't need the strings until you **display** the card values; just put them in an array and use the `suit` value as an index.